# Reason why the image point is most clear?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I just want to confirm my intuitve understanding of the image point.

The reason why it's not clear elsewhere is because one point from the object going through the convex lens will be larger than its actual size if it's not at the image point, hence interfering with other points from the object.

So it would be like each drop of paint on a painting spreading radially outwards, right?

Comment: I think that you've got the right idea. The photons from one point on the object going through the convex lens will in general be spread out and land at different locations on an image plane. So a point on the object becomes a diffuse spot on the image plane. Only if the image plane is placed at the proper focal distance do all the photons from a point on the object converge to a corresponding sharp point on the image plane.

Answer (score 0):

Although interference between adjacent point images can occur, the reason a focused spot gets larger as you move away from the optimally focused point in the image plane is not due to interference between adjacent point images.  This can be tested by using single point objects in various positions in the object plane and measuring the size of the resulting point images.

Any real lens (as opposed to an ideal lens) has aberrations that can be corrected optimally for one point in the image plane, but which cannot be corrected for all points in the image plane. The optimally focused point will have the form of (approximately) a round Gaussian spot. If a single object point is imaged onto the image plane a small distance away from that one optimally focused point, its image wlll be distorted into an oval quasi-Gaussian spot.  As the imaged point moves farther (in the image plane) away from the optimally focused point, that distortion gets steadily worse, sometimes even forming a tail like a comet.  A good explanation of aberrations is found [here](http://www.astrosurf.com/luxorion/report-aberrations2.htm).  Particularly relevant to your question is "coma", illustrated in the third figure in that reference.